# Specify thousand separator in ssrs without specifying decimal

Tags: reporting-services, number-formatting, ssrs-2012

MY database have values like
3302540.8200
748712.9600
584879.2400
20787.5300
1338075.0000

I need the above values like below in my SSRS reports
3,302,540.82
748,712.96
584,879.24
20,787.53
1,338,075

I tried custom format for number on my text box  #,0.######## but while exporting it in excel it is showing the value 1 as 1. (dot is not desirable)

help me with this.
TIA

Comment: can't you just use a normal number format with , separators and 2 deecimal places?

Comment: I can't specify 2 decimal places. If the value in db is 12345.12300 then my report should show 12,345.123. Appending 0 after decimal and applying thousand separator on the value is what i require.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the following as the datasource:

```
SELECT 3302540.8200 Number UNION
SELECT 748712.9600 UNION
SELECT 584879.2400 UNION
SELECT 20787.5300 UNION
SELECT 1338075.0000 UNION
SELECT 1000 UNION
SELECT 10123.20
```

You could use the following expression in your output table/Textbox:

```
=Format(Fields!Number.Value,"#,#.##")
```

Excel Output:

```
1,000
10,123.2
20,787.53
584,879.24
748,712.96
1,338,075
3,302,540.82
```

Comment: Louie, i don't want to specify Decimal places. (you have set to 2). Need to use 1000 separator without specifying decimal.

Comment: Any leads yet??

Comment: Novice - have you tested the solution i've proposed? This works, and I've tested this in Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS)/Excel.

Comment: @Louie It works for me in American format. How would be this in European format? I tried to do the same just inverting dot and comma and it didn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

in your designed report in SSRS ,
type  below in format section of your textBox

#,0;(#,0)

it works exactly as what u want